# Reload Lucene Suggester Index

Tags: lucene

How do I store and reload a Lucene suggester index?

This is how a build a Suggester index:

```
def buildAutoCompleteIndex(path:Path, data:List[Map[String,Any]])
  :BlendedInfixSuggester = {
    val directory = FSDirectory.open(path)
    val autoComplete = new BlendedInfixSuggester(directory, new StandardAnalyzer())
    autoComplete.build(new EntityIteratorStub())

    data.map { d =>
      autoComplete.add(d("text").asInstanceOf[BytesRef],
       d("contexts").asInstanceOf[Set[BytesRef]],
       d("weight").asInstanceOf[Long],
       d("payload").asInstanceOf[BytesRef])
    }
    autoComplete.refresh

    autoComplete
  }
```

However, if I try to check if the index exists on, say, server restart, I get a "suggester was not built" exception.

```
def checkIfIndexExists(path:Path):BlendedInfixSuggester = {
  val directory = FSDirectory.open(path)
  val autoComplete = new BlendedInfixSuggester(directory, new StandardAnalyzer())

  try {
    // exception occurs here ->
    if (autoComplete.lookup("a", 1, true, false).length > 0) autoComplete
    else null
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(e) => {
      println("Index does not exist, recreating at " + path)
      null
    }
  }
}
```

Edit ==========================

Found this in Lucene `AnalyzingInfixSuggester`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean store(DataOutput in) throws IOException {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean load(DataInput out) throws IOException {
    return false;
  }
```

Does this mean that storing-reloading of Suggester indexes cannot be done?

Comment: Try `commit` method instead.

Comment: Yep, commit worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using commit solved the problem.

```
def checkIfIndexExists(path:Path):BlendedInfixSuggester = {
  val directory = FSDirectory.open(path)

  val autoComplete = new BlendedInfixSuggester(directory, new StandardAnalyzer())

  try {
    if (autoComplete.getCount > 0) autoComplete
    else null
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(e) => null
  }
}


def buildAutoCompleteIndex(path:Path, data:List[Map[String,Any]])
:BlendedInfixSuggester = {
  val directory = FSDirectory.open(path)

  val autoComplete = new BlendedInfixSuggester(directory, new StandardAnalyzer())

  // Just build a stub iterator to get started with
  autoComplete.build(new EntityIteratorStub())

  data.map { d =>
    autoComplete.add(d("text").asInstanceOf[BytesRef],
     d("contexts").asInstanceOf[Set[BytesRef]],
     d("weight").asInstanceOf[Long],
     d("payload").asInstanceOf[BytesRef])
  }
  autoComplete.refresh
  autoComplete.commit

  autoComplete
}
```